# Compute the degree of finite field extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> Compute the degree $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}, \sqrt{3 + \sqrt{3}}) : \mathbb{Q}]$.

By the Degree Theorem we have $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}, \sqrt{3 + \sqrt{3}}) : \mathbb{Q}] = [\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}, \sqrt{3 + \sqrt{3}}) : \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3 + \sqrt{3}})] \cdot [\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3 + \sqrt{3}}) : \mathbb{Q}]$.

Now, $\alpha = \sqrt{3 + \sqrt{3}} \iff \alpha^{2} = 3 + \sqrt{3} \iff \alpha^{2} - 3 = \sqrt{3} \iff \alpha^{4} - 6 \alpha^{2} + 6 = 0$. Which means that $\alpha = \sqrt{3 + \sqrt{3}}$ is a zero of $m(x) = x^{4} - 6 x^{2} + 6$. Now, $m$ is monic and Eisenstein with prime $p = 3$. Hence, $m$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ and is thus the minimal polynomial. Hence we have $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3 + \sqrt{3}}) : \mathbb{Q}] = \text{deg}(m) = 4$.

To compute $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}, \sqrt{3 + \sqrt{3}}) : \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3 + \sqrt{3}})]$, we need to find the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{3}$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3 + \sqrt{3}})$.

**This is where I am stuck.**

Perhaps there might be a different solution if for instance $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}, \sqrt{3 + \sqrt{3}}) = \mathbb{Q}(\bullet)$, but I can't seem to find such a field.

**Also, can someone give me some general strategy on how to solve such problems? Perhaps some tips or what to watch out for given your experience.**

Comment: It is probably much easier to consider the tower $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}, \sqrt{3 + \sqrt{3}})/\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})/\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: But for sure, your method works - notice that $\sqrt{3} = \alpha^2 - 3$ so the degree is 1 for the second extension.

Comment: So I must be missing something but I came to the same result with $\sqrt{3} = \alpha^{2} - 3$ but I can't see why this is the minimal polynomial of degree 1.

Comment: $\alpha^2-3$ is already contained in $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$, so its minimal polynomial is linear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do it.
First of all, consider both $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3+\sqrt{3}} ): \mathbb{Q}]$ and $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3} ): \mathbb{Q}]$. The first is $4$ as you have stated and the second is $2$, so this gives you the hint that $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3},\sqrt{3+\sqrt{3}} ): \mathbb{Q}]$ is a multiple of $4$.
I want to prove that it is exactly $4$. Therefore I have to prove that $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3},\sqrt{3+\sqrt{3}} ): \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3+\sqrt{3}})]=1$. That is equivalent to checking that I can express $\sqrt{3}$ as an element of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3+\sqrt{3}})$. All the elements of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3+\sqrt{3}})$ are like this:
$$\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt{3+\sqrt{3}}\right) = \left\{ a+b\sqrt{3+\sqrt{3}} + c\left(\sqrt{3+\sqrt{3}}\right)^2: a, b, c \in \mathbb{Q}\right\} = \left\{ a+b\sqrt{3+\sqrt{3}} + 3c + c\sqrt{3}: a, b, c \in \mathbb{Q}\right\}$$
Choosing $a = -3$, $b = 0$ and $c = 1$ you get that
$$\sqrt{3} \in \mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt{3+\sqrt{3}}\right)$$
Therefore, as $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3},\sqrt{3+\sqrt{3}} ): \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3+\sqrt{3}})]=1$ we have that
$$[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3},\sqrt{3+\sqrt{3}} ): \mathbb{Q}] = [\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3+\sqrt{3}} ): \mathbb{Q}] \cdot [\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3},\sqrt{3+\sqrt{3}} ): \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3+\sqrt{3}})] = 4 \cdot 1 = 4$$

Comment: But now if you can express $\sqrt{3}$ as an element of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3 + \sqrt{3}})$, then this means that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3 + \sqrt{3}}) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}, \sqrt{3 + \sqrt{3}})$, since $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3 + \sqrt{3}})$ is the smallest field containing $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\sqrt{3 + \sqrt{3}}$ and similarly $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}, \sqrt{3 + \sqrt{3}})$ is the smallest field containing $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\sqrt{3}$ and $\sqrt{3 + \sqrt{3}}$. Hence, we can compute instead $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3 + \sqrt{3}}):\mathbb{Q}]$ which yields the minimal polynomial of degree $4$ and we are done, right?

Comment: @Chelioss That's right. I edited my post to make it clearer

Comment: Thanks. How do you know how the elements in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3 + \sqrt{3}})$ look like? Knowing that made the problem much simpler.

Comment: Let $\alpha = \sqrt{3+\sqrt{3}}$. An element of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i \cdot \alpha ^i$ where $a_i \in \mathbb{Q}$. The thing is that here the $n$ of the sum is $3$ (try by yourself to operate with $n=4$ and see what happens)